# Monitor SMART Values of a SAS/SCSI drive with Munin

Tags: munin, sas, smart

I'm trying to monitor my two SAS drives using the SMART Tools Plugin for MUNIN.
On SATA drives its no problem, all SMART values are being shown.
It seems that smartctl doesn't output valuable SMART values for SAS drives:

On Debian Squeeze with two SAS Drives "smartctl -A /dev/sda" outputs:

```
smartctl 5.40 2010-07-12 r3124 [x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-10 by Bruce Allen, http://smartmontools.sourceforge.net

Current Drive Temperature:     43 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        85 C
Manufactured in week 10 of year 2012
Specified cycle count over device lifetime:  50000
Accumulated start-stop cycles:  6
Elements in grown defect list: 0
Vendor (Seagate) cache information
Blocks sent to initiator = 765815905320960
```

There is no information like on a SATA drive:

```
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG VALUE  WORST THRESH  TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   099   099   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       2376
3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   091   091   011    Pre-fail  Always       -       3620
4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       405
......
```

Comment: are you using this one? .. http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/plugin-smart_   also can you include distro and version

Comment: Yes, I'm using this plugin. Distribution is Debian GNU/Linux 6.0 (Squeeze)

Answer (score 2):

S.M.A.R.T. is implemented in different ways in SCSI (SAS) and ATA (SATA) drives -- in particular, there is no concept of attributes in SCSI drives.

Answer (score 1):

S.M.A.R.T. is a feature of ATA disks. Instead, SAS/SCSI disks are using [SCSI mode page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SCSI_mode_page).

You can use hdsentinel to get some SAS/SCSI stat, but don't expect detailed info like SATA.
`./HDSentinel -dump -dev /dev/sdf`